# What is a best strategy to clone Git repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm apologizing if my question has been already answered, I wasn't able to find a best solution for my particular case.

We have a Git repository with a few branches that can't be merged into origin branch. And now we need to clone this repository with all branches so we can go a different way.

The repository in hosted on GitLab. I believe that a best approach would be to simply copy the repository and upload it again in our own space.

But unfortunately, due to our bureaucracy it's a time-taking process. Alternatively we can simply fork the repository and I wonder if it will give us some troubles in future?

Thank you!

Comment: Di you have access to repo?

Comment: Will you push changes in future to both repos (new and old one) or just to new? @alexxjk

Comment: @dunajski just to new

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy I can clone and push but I don't have a permission to create a new one

Comment: What do you mean by "can't be merged into origin branch"? What is this `origin` branch? Don't you mean `master` branch? And why do you think "cloning" the repo will help?

Comment: If you clone the repo, you will have exactly the same branches and everything that you currently have so I don't see how that will help.

Comment: @Matt I can't merge them not for technical reasons. It's just how things are in our company..

Comment: You didn't answer my questions : `What is this origin branch? Don't you mean master branch? And why do you think "cloning" the repo will help?`

Comment: @Matt Sorry for the confusion, I meant that to simply copy the repo would be the best scenario, but it's not that simple in our case. Yes, I meant the master branch.

Answer (score 3):

In your specified situation I'll do.

1. Clone repo `git clone [url]` to new destination.
2. Then check remotes `git remotes -v`.
3. Set remote url to new destination `git remote set-url {remote_name} url`.
4. Try to push something by `git push remote_name branch_name`

Answer (score 0):

In Gitlab UI, you can create a new project by specifying a git repo url.

[image]

This will import the content of the referenced repository. Be aware that the import will time out after 180 minutes (Gitlab advices the git clone/push combination describe by @dunajski for big repo.